# I want to show footer below a section

Tags: html, css, sass, z-index

I have a challenge from my Front-end mentor, and I want to make the footer below the cta-card section
as you can see on the screen

[image]

but even when I change the z-index it doesn't affect it at all.

here is the link to the project page : https://cheerfuldev1.github.io/HuddleLandingPage/

Also here is a link to the repo in github : https://github.com/CheerFulDev1/HuddleLandingPage

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Post CODE, not PICTURES of code or just links to your site

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: add `position: relative` and a background color to the `.cta-card .card` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consult this [short article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) from css tricks.
The most common use-case where z-index is not working is where one or more elements do not have a `position` property set to either `absolute` or `relative`

> z-index only affects elements that have a position value other than static (the default).

z-index worries aside, it seems that z-index is not actually used on the example page, you can find this out by inspecting the rendered html for the footer.

Comment: thank you so much it worked!, i didn't need to add z-index, just by changing it to relative position, bgc white, it's fixed thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To extend on @Scott Anderson his answer,

He is right you need to set the `position` property try the following css

```
.cta-card {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.cta-card .card {
    background-color: white;
}
```

the first block is to use z-index and have the footer appear behind it.

The second block is so that the card has a white background as it didn't have it in your example

Comment: thank you so much it worked!, i didn't need to add z-index, just by changing it to relative position, bgc white, it's fixed thank you!